# Facebook Share URL in list to detail pages (JS)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

On my webpage I have a list of news articles, where every entry has a facebook share to its detail page:

http://steuerberater-steiermark.at/Pages/News

I have set the Open Graph Markup on every detail page, but the facebook-share popup only scans the current list page and not the detail page of the shared URL.

How can I tell facebook to take title, image, description from the shared URL???

Comment: _“I have set the Open Graph Markup on every detail page”_ – I don’t see any `og` meta tags in the source code of for example http://www.haydn.st/Pages/News?nid=30033, and [neither does the FB scraper](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.haydn.st%2FPages%2FNews%3Fnid%3D30033).

Comment: When you open http://www.haydn.st/Pages/News?nid=302962, you can find the meta tags:

 <meta name="twitter:card" value="summary">
<meta property="og:title" content="Änderungen bei kleinen Vereinsfesten">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.haydn.st/Pages/News?nid=302962"><meta property="og:image" content="http://www.infomedia.co.at/admin/attachments/kfv3470dlj.jpg">
<meta property="og:description" content="Ein kleines Vereinsfest kann....">

Comment: But your share button on the News page for that very article shares the URL `http://www.haydn.st/Pages/News?nid=30033`. And that does not have any of those tags set.